# Magento 2 Installation on Linux MInt

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to install magento 2 over linux mint just to explore and for knowledge but i am getting lot difficulties in permissions sometimes commands does not run do anyone knows a best tutorial that i could follow in order to install

Comment: this link - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-install-magento-2-ubuntu.html . Best explained in for how to install magento and mange

Comment: Thanks @MohitPatel i have already tried that but that does not seems okay for a beginner

Comment: magento 2 installation time showing any error?

Comment: actually i was facing error while running cli commands

Comment: which error Please add error in your question

Comment: wait am installing it again and will update this question thanks @MohitPatel

Comment: Hello i am find one link i think it is best for beginner - https://websiteforstudents.com/install-magento-2-using-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-1-support/

Comment: yep thats great

Comment: yeah mohit its good  you can post it as an ans that could be very handy for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this link follow all step by step:-

1.) **https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-install-magento-2-ubuntu.html**

2.) **https://websiteforstudents.com/install-magento-2-using-composer-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-1-support/**

**`THANKS.`**

**Update:-** https://tecadmin.net/install-magento-ubuntu-18-04/ this one is also great

Comment: am updating your ans with another link kindly approve as this is also great for beginner and it helped me